# User is able to click a button multiple times when it should close the form after the first click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

On the main page, there's a button which popups a dialog prompting the user for their username and password. When they click "Save", the credentials are validated (both JS & SQL) and the window either closes, or tells them their credentials are invalid.

I'm experiencing some weird behavior though, where I can mash the button infinitely and then the "Save" action is performed multiple times.

On the `Page_Load`, we attach a Javascript 'event' to the button like so:

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return ValidateUserPasswordSignPopup('" & txtUsername.ClientID & "', '" & txtPassword.ClientID & "');")
```

---

Javascript validation:

```
function ValidateUserPasswordSignPopup(userTxtBox, PassTxtBox)
{
    var userTextBoxctrl = document.getElementById(userTxtBox)
    var PassTxtBoxctrl = document.getElementById(PassTxtBox)

    if (userTextBoxctrl.value.trim() == '') {
        alert("Please enter User Name.")
        document.getElementById(userTxtBox).focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (PassTxtBoxctrl.value.trim() == '')
    {
        alert("Please enter Password.")
        document.getElementById(PassTxtBox).focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

Button click:

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    If SaveData() Then
        Response.Write("<script language = JavaScript>window.returnValue='yes';self.close();</script>")
    End If

End Sub
```

---

`SaveData()` just creates a few objects, runs a stored procedure, creates a few more objects, then creates a `DataTable` which is passed to another method and is saved to the DB. Nothing too intense.

I've tried adding code in the JS method to disable the button, then at the end of the code-side click event I re-enable it, but the window seems to hang infinitely that way.

I've also tried toggling its state between the JS (re-enabling it before each `return` / at the end) and then re-disabling it at the start of the click event and re-enabling it again at the end of the click event, but I'm still able to click the button multiple times with this route.

Anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

**EDIT** My initial thought was the time it takes for the Javascript to run, as brief of a script as it is, was allowing the user to re-click the button before the postback happens to handle the click event. I completely removed the script that gets added in the `Page_Load`, in the first block of code above, but the behavior still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is able to click the button multiple times due to the lag between form submission to the server and response content coming from the server.

Disable or hide the button just before `return true;` in `ValidateUserPasswordSignPopup`.

Another way:

```
var submittedFlag = false;
function ValidateUserPasswordSignPopup(userTxtBox, PassTxtBox)
{
  if (submittedFlag)
    return false;

  ...

  submittedFlag = true;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: As noted in my last paragraph, before the EDIT, I tried toggling the enabled state in Javascript the and in the code. I also tried removing the Javascript entirely. Neither fixed the issue. That said, your second idea with the `submittedFlag` *did* work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Response.Write, try registering the JavaScript using the [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) Method.

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    If SaveData() Then

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "YourKey", _
                                                    "<script language = JavaScript>window.returnValue='yes';self.close();</script>")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  This worked for me when I tested it.  Try using the Developer Tools of the browser to see if it indicates some issue. Perhaps there is something we're missing.